# Proving if $\frac{nx}{e^{nx}}$ converges uniformly

Tags: uniform-convergence

I have this expression
$$
\frac{nx}{e^{nx}} \qquad x\geq 0
$$
and I had to test if it's pointwise and uniformly convergent(separately). Pointwise convergence could be easily proved by just evaluating the limit below
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{nx}{e^{nx}}\to 0
$$
To prove uniform convergence I had to evaluate this limit and prove that its equal to $0$
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\left|\frac{nx}{e^{nx}} - 0\right|\right|
$$
I'm a little confused by how im supposed to calculate the above, is the supremum with respect to $n$ or $x$? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Comment: Supremum is with respect of $x$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It does not uniformly converge to $0$, as
$$\sup_{x \geq 0} \frac{nx}{e^{nx}} = \frac{n \times \frac{1}{n}}{e^{n \frac{1}{n}}} = \frac{1}{e}$$
which doesn't tend to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: Supremum doesnt have to be equal to $\frac{1}{e}$, but it is equal or higher so the argument holds.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I was a little confused by supremum of a function with 2 variables in it. I think you calculated the extreme point of the function to $\frac{1}{n}$ to get the supremum, right?

Comment: @JamMaster Exactly.

Comment: @JamMaster $\frac{d(nxe^{-nx})}{dx}=(n-n^2x)e^{-nx}=0\implies x=1/n$ and for $x=1/n$, we have $nxe^{-nx}=1/e$.